# Display Multiple Figures in Same Notebook Cell

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have several example of data in lists.

```
data1 = [91.0, 199.0, 298.0, 271.0, 129.0, 320.0, 104.0, 177.0, 236.0, 89.0, 229.0, 274.0, 239.0,
246.0, 91.0, 199.0, 298.0, 271.0, 129.0, 320.0, 104.0, 177.0, 236.0, 89.0, 229.0, 274.0, 239.0,
246.0]
data2 = [1,5,7,12,5,9,7,2,2,3,15,17,11,5,8,3,1,5,1]
...
```

In one cell I want to display a histogram for each of these datasets. I've tried this:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2)
hist1 = plt.hist(data1, label='First graph').plot(ax=axs[0])
```

but I get an error

Also if I just do this:

```
plt.hist(data1)
plt.hist(data2)
```

it just displays the first one

Comment: `axs[0].hist`...`axs[1].hist`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I figured out from a comment

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2)
axs[0].hist(data1)
axs[1].hist(data2)
...
```